# How copy an array's contents into two smaller arrays of unequal size

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to copy contents of a larger array to two smaller arrays of an unequal size each (of which size may change according to the program). I have four arrays at the simplified code below:

```
#define size 20
double bigArray[size]={14.553,13.653,9.555,8.564..and so on...9.324,11.123};
/*IndicatorArray is associated to bigArray as follows:
 if bigArray[i]<10 then indicatorArray[i]=10 else =20 */
int indicatorArray[size]={20,20,10,10,..and so on..};
double array10[count10], array20[count20]; /*count10 and count20 are 
counters from indicatorArray passed as a size of each array 
in earlier function not shown here*/
for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        if (indicatorArray[i]==10) {
            arr10[i]=bigArray[i];
        //  printf("%lf ",arr10[i]); /*this shows me correct results*/
        }
        else {
            arr20[i]=bigArray[i];
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<count10;i++){
        printf("%lf ",arr10[i]);
    }
    printf("\n \n");
    for (i=0;i<count20;i++){
        printf("%lf ",arr20[i]);
    }
```

The result is something like

00.0000 00.0000 9.555 8.564 11.123 14.666 ....

14.553 13.653 00.000......00.000

but I don't want zeros to appear or have such disrupted results but something like

9.55 8.564 ...... 7.123
and
14.533 13.653 .....11.123

Why does this happen and how to do it in the right way?

Comment: When copying data in C, use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). As long as you know the sizes of the three arrays, and that neither destination size will cause you to go out of bounds of the source array, then there's really no problem.

Comment: As to get a pointer to a specific element of the source array, simply use the address-of operator `&`. As in `&bigArray[10]` which will give you a pointer to the eleventh element.

Comment: When you place values from bigarray[i] into arr20[i] or arr10[i], this means they are put into the array at the same position that they were found in the big array. So if they are in the big array at position 3, they will be put into the smaller array at position 3 with 0's for 0 - 2. You might want to use a counter to track  the "i" position for the smaller arrays if you don't want them to skip positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, when splitting the contents of an array, recognize each element is located in a specific addressable place in memory, making this a perfect job for *[memcpy()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm)*.  Here is a simple illustration using that concept:

```
int main(void)
{
    double source[] = {3.4,5.6,2.3,4.5,6.7,8.9,10.1,11.1,12.3,4.5};
    double split1[3];
    double split2[7];

    memcpy(split1, &source[0], 3*sizeof(double));
    memcpy(split2, &source[3], 7*sizeof(double));

    return 0;   
}
```

If your project has well defined and static parameters that are known at runtime, then using a few common macros, and some additional variables, this could be made a little more general.

The following example does essentially the same as the illustration above, but in a loop, potentially a more adaptable construct.

```
#define SPLIT_CNT 3

int main(void)
{
    double source[] = {3.4,5.6,2.3,4.5,6.7,8.9,10.1,11.1,12.3,4.5,8.5,9.5};
    double split1[3];                         // arrays if differing sizes
    double split2[7];
    double split3[2];
    size_t start_pos;                         //position accumulator
    size_t cpy_len[SPLIT_CNT] = {3,7,2};      //known array sections
    double *split[] = {split1,split2,split3}; //enables looping on arrays of differing sizes
    start_pos = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<SPLIT_CNT;i++)
    {
        if(i > 0)start_pos += cpy_len[i-1]; //move the start postition  
        memcpy(split[i], &source[start_pos], sizeof(double)*cpy_len[i]);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: selected as the right answer because of the effort you ve done and because memcpy is the way to go. However, I used Patrick's solution for my program as I wanted to avoid the memcpy for now.

Answer (score 1):

As someprogrammerdude commented, you should look into using memcpy when copying data. If you still want to use your implementation instead, the problem lies with how you use `i` in the for loop. Remember that in this instance, `i` will be the position in the big array that the number you want to copy appears. If you want the first element you copy from the big array to be in position 0 of one of the smaller arrays, there's no way that will happen for both if you use `arr10[i]` and `arr20[i]`. Instead you can use a counter for each smaller array and increment each time an element goes into it. Here's a quick example I did with an online compiler after hard coding some values:

```
int arr10Count = 0;
int arr20Count = 0;

int i;
for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        if (indicatorArray[i]==10) {
            arr10[arr10Count]=bigArray[i];
            arr10Count++;
        //  printf("%lf ",arr10[i]); /*this shows me correct results*/
        }
        else {
            arr20[arr20Count]=bigArray[i];
            arr20Count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It also works like this: arr10[arr10Count++]=bigArray[i];  Thank you Patrick for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate counters for the index in `array10` and `array20`.

```
#define size 20

double bigArray[size]={14.553,13.653,9.555,8.564..and so on...9.324,11.123};

/*IndicatorArray is associated to bigArray as follows:
 if bigArray[i]<10 then indicatorArray[i]=10 else =20 */
int indicatorArray[size]={20,20,10,10,..and so on..};

double array10[count10], array20[count20]; /*count10 and count20 are 
counters from indicatorArray passed as a size of each array 
in earlier function not shown here*/

size_t i10; /* index for array10 *** */
size_t i20; /* index for array20 *** */

for (i=0, i10=0, i20=0; i<size; i++){
        if (indicatorArray[i]==10) {
            if(i10 < count10) { /* prevent array index out of range *** */
                arr10[i10++]=bigArray[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            if(i20 < count20) { /* prevent array index out of range *** */
                arr20[i20++]=bigArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<count10;i++){
        printf("%lf ",arr10[i]);
    }
    printf("\n \n");
    for (i=0;i<count20;i++){
        printf("%lf ",arr20[i]);
    }
```